# Selenium Webdriver Xpath id random

Tags: python, selenium, google-chrome, webdriver

I have a problem,
when I look for the id of an xpath it changes every time I enter the web

how can i use selenium webdriver python
browser.find_element(By.ID,)
if the id changes every time I consult it

first

```
<span data-dojo-attach-point="containerNode,focusNode" 
class="tabLabel" role="tab" tabindex="0" 
id="icm_widget_SelectorTabContainer_0_tablist_dcf42e75-1d03-4acd-878c-722cbc8e74ec" 
name="icm_widget_SelectorTabContainer_0_tablist_dcf42e75-1d03-4acd-878c-722cbc8e74ec" 
aria-disabled="false" 
title="" 
style="user-select: none;" 
aria-selected="true">Search</span>
```

second

```
<span data-dojo-attach-point="containerNode,focusNode" 
class="tabLabel" 
role="tab" 
tabindex="0" 
id="icm_widget_SelectorTabContainer_0_tablist_c9ba5042-90d2-4932-8c2d-762a1dd39982"
name="icm_widget_SelectorTabContainer_0_tablist_c9ba5042-90d2-4932-8c2d-762a1dd39982" 
aria-disabled="false" 
title="" 
style="user-select: none;" 
aria-selected="true">Search</span>
```

try with

```
browser.find_element(By.XPATH
browser.find_element(By.ID
browser.find_element(By.NAME
```

same problem, the id changes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use below xpath

```
browser.find_element(By.XPATH(//span[contains(@id, 'icm_widget_SelectorTabContainer') and text()='Search']);
```

Comment: This is not a valid XPath expression. And not a valid syntax for `find_element` method

Answer (score 0):

In case the first part of the id is unique and stable as it seems to be, you can use XPath or CSS Selector to locate this element.
XPath:

```py
browser.find_element(By.XPATH, "//span[contains(@id,'icm_widget_SelectorTabContainer_0_tablist')]")
```

CSS Selector:

```py
browser.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "span[id*='icm_widget_SelectorTabContainer_0_tablist']")
```